# How can I show that :$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}(\zeta(n+1)-1))=\frac12$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, riemann-zeta

A few computations I did with Mathematica gave me this sum. I'm really very interested to know how I can evaluate $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}(\zeta(n+1)-1))=\frac12$$ I have used Direchlet eta function to show it but that didn't succeed since the value of zeta here is related only to an integer.

Comment: This was already asked, and proven like below, on the site.

Comment: ...Several times, as the pages listed on the right column called "Related", show.

Comment: Probably you meant that :https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2020152/156150

Comment: Not specifically. As I said, a cursory glance at the "Related" column reveals several posts zero or one or two clicks away.

Answer (score 6):

\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1}(\zeta(n+1)-1) &=& \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1} \sum_{m=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{m^{n+1}} \\
\end{eqnarray*}\begin{eqnarray*}&=& \sum_{m=2}^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}   \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{m^{n+1}} \\
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}&=& \sum_{m=2}^{\infty}    \frac{1}{m(m+1)}=\frac{1}{2} \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Use partial fractions and telescoping to do the final sum.

Comment: Thanks for the slick answer